# Not found ffmpeg when try run in scratch image

Tags: docker

I have built a Golang image using alpine, my code has functions that need to convert videos using ffmpeg.
My problem is when I try to run ffmpeg on a scratch image, I try to copy the binaries but it doesn't work when my code tries to run ffmpeg.

```
FROM mwader/static-ffmpeg:5.1 as FFmpeg
FROM golang:alpine AS builder


# Add dependencies
RUN apk add git
RUN apk --no-cache add tzdata
RUN apk add --no-cache ffmpeg

# Set necessary environmet variables needed for our image
ENV GO111MODULE=on \
    CGO_ENABLED=0 \
    GOOS=linux \
    GOARCH=amd64

# Move to working directory /build
WORKDIR /build

# Copy and download dependency using go mod
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download

# Copy the code into the container
COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN go build -o main .

# Move to /dist directory as the place for resulting binary folder
WORKDIR /dist

# Copy binary from build to main folder
RUN cp /build/main .
RUN cp /build/dev.env .

# Build a small image
FROM scratch

#Copy from builder bin
COPY --from=builder /dist/main /
COPY --from=builder /build/dev.env .
COPY --from=builder /usr/share/zoneinfo /usr/share/zoneinfo
COPY --from=FFmpeg /ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/
COPY --from=FFmpeg /ffprobe /usr/local/bin/

#Set Timezone
ENV TZ="America/Montevideo"

# Copy certificates
COPY --from=builder /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt /etc/ssl/certs/

# Expose port out container
EXPOSE 8080

# Command to run
CMD ["/main"]
```

I expect run ffmpeg into scratch image.

Comment: Could you share the exact error message you get?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.